# Null Pointer Exception (Location Services)

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, geolocation, maps

I am trying to learn how to location services and I got Null Pointer Exception when I tried to mark the my location on the map. Kindly help me remove this exception.

LogCat -

```
07-27 00:02:08.169: E/AndroidRuntime(304): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-27 00:02:08.169: E/AndroidRuntime(304): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-27 00:02:08.169: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at com.google.android.maps.PixelConverter.toPixels(PixelConverter.java:71)
07-27 00:02:08.169: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at com.google.android.maps.PixelConverter.toPixels(PixelConverter.java:61)
07-27 00:02:08.169: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at com.sanjay.map.Map$MyLocationOverlay.draw(Map.java:116)
07-27 00:02:08.169: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at com.google.android.maps.OverlayBundle.draw(OverlayBundle.java:42)
07-27 00:02:08.169: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onDraw(MapView.java:494)
07-27 00:02:08.169: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6740)
07-27 00:02:08.169: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
07-27 00:02:08.169: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
07-27 00:02:08.169: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
07-27 00:02:08.169: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
07-27 00:02:08.169: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
07-27 00:02:08.169: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
07-27 00:02:08.169: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
07-27 00:02:08.169: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
07-27 00:02:08.169: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
07-27 00:02:08.169: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
07-27 00:02:08.169: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
07-27 00:02:08.169: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
07-27 00:02:08.169: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1842)
07-27 00:02:08.169: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1407)
07-27 00:02:08.169: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1163)
07-27 00:02:08.169: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
07-27 00:02:08.169: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-27 00:02:08.169: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-27 00:02:08.169: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-27 00:02:08.169: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-27 00:02:08.169: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-27 00:02:08.169: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-27 00:02:08.169: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-27 00:02:08.169: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Activity -

```
package com.sanjay.map;

import java.util.List;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;  
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;

public class Map extends MapActivity {


MapController mapController;
MapView mapview;
 GeoPoint p=null;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mapview = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapview.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapController = mapview.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(16);

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        private TextView locationDetails;

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            makeUseOfNewLocation(location);
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New Locationdd", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        private void makeUseOfNewLocation(Location location) {


            double lon = (double) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6);
            double lat = (double) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6);

            int lontitue = (int)lon;
            int latitute = (int)lat;

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New Lontitue = "+ lontitue +"\n New Latitute = "+ latitute, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            locationDetails = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewMap);
            locationDetails.setText("New Lontitue = "+ lontitue +"\n New Latitute = "+ latitute);

            GeoPoint geopoint = new GeoPoint(latitute, lontitue);
            mapController.animateTo(geopoint);

            MyLocationOverlay myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay();
            List<Overlay> list = mapview.getOverlays();
            list.add(myLocationOverlay);


            //mapview.invalidate();
        }
    };

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}


public class MyLocationOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay {

@Override
public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
    // Converts lat/lng-Point to OUR coordinates on the screen.
    Point myScreenCoords = new Point();
    mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p, myScreenCoords);

    paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
    paint.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.marker);

    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, myScreenCoords.x, myScreenCoords.y, paint);
    canvas.drawText("You are here!", myScreenCoords.x, myScreenCoords.y, paint);
    return true;
}
}
}
```

Manifest -

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.sanjay.map"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" /> 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> 



<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <activity
        android:name=".Map"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_map" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Layout -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">


<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Waiting for location..."
android:id="@+id/textViewMap"/>




 <com.google.android.maps.MapView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/mapview"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:clickable="true"
  android:apiKey="/*My_KEY*/">


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Seems like toPixels() is throwing the exception, leading one to believe that mapView.getProjection() is returning null. Put in a check to see if that's the case, and go from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `GeoPoint` called p that you create at the top of the class is `null`. You never set it to something else. So you are effectively calling `toPixels(null, myScreenCoords);`